# How to run Regex in Python on a Dataframe in Apache Spark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark

I'm trying run a Regex in Python on a dataframe in Apache Spark.

The df is

[image]

The regex is as follows:

```
import re
m = re.search("[Pp]ython", df)
print(m)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The following will work

import re
m = re.search("[Pp]ython", 'Python python')
print(m)

But I would like the regex to work on a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [["Python"],["python"], ["Scala"], ["PYTHON"]]
schema= ["language"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = df.withColumn("extracted", F.regexp_extract("language", "[Pp]ython", 0))
```

Result:

```
+--------+---------+
|language|extracted|
+--------+---------+
|  Python|   Python|
|  python|   python|
|   Scala|         |
|  PYTHON|         |
+--------+---------+
```

The definition for [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)

The second parameter being a string, this function cannot work with Spark dataframes. However (at least most) patterns that work with `re.search` will also work for `regexp_extract`. So testing the patterns with `re.search` first might be a way.

Comment: thanks for getting touch. That's a great solution, however I'm a real novice with RegEx. I'm testing using re.search() with import re. Is it not possible to use re.search() with a dataframe?

Comment: @Patterson unfortunately no. re.search works on a string and you are looking for a solution that works on a column of a dataframe